# recordset advance query

Tags: html

I'd like to have a query for the first and last name on an enrollment list so that only one result show. However, if only the last name is chosen in the query multiple answers will show.

Comment: @Tom: You really need to provide more information.

Comment: @Tom A few things that might help ... the type of SQL server you are using, the language(s) you are coding in, and the portion of the code that you think is behind the problem are a few of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` the last name field in your query.

For example if you had this data:

```
MyTable:
id last_name first_name
1  Smith     John
2  Smith     Jane
3  Jones     Paul
```

Running a query like this:

```
SELECT t.last_name 
  FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.last_name
ORDER BY t.last_name
```

...would return these two rows:

```
Jones
Smith
```

Comment: I'm using mysql as the database and php. I'm also woeking with dreamweaver.  I can do a simple query (like the one above) however, I can't do a query that has more than one answer. I'd like to query by both the first and last name. So if I have more than one "Smith" I can get the right one.